# Linear Regression Error in Eval object 'MEDV' not found

Tags: r, linear-regression

what is wrong with my code? I'm getting
**Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'MEDV' not found**

```
housing.df<-read.csv("BostonHousing.csv")
# use first 500 rows of data
housing.df <- housing.df[1:500, ]
set.seed(1)
#random select 100 records. sample function does not return data frame. It only returns row index
housing1.index<- sample (nrow (housing.df), 100)
housing1.index #the 100 random rows selected
housing1.df<- housing.df[housing1.index, ]
head (housing1.df) #data frame with 1000 random sample
selected.var <- c(1, 4, 6)
selected.var
set.seed(1)  # set seed for reproducing the partition
#random select 350 rows's index among 1000 rows of data (350 is 70% of 500)
train.index <- sample(c(1:500), 350) 
train.index
# save selected 350 rows and variables in training.df data frame
train.df <- housing.df[train.index, selected.var]
head (train.df)
# save selected the rest 150 rows and variables in valid.df data fram
valid.df <- housing.df[-train.index, selected.var]
# use lm() to run a linear regression of Price on all 11 predictors in the
# training set. 
# use . after ~ to include all the remaining columns in train.df as predictors.
housing.lm <- lm(MEDV ~ ., data = train.df)
```

Comment: What does `names(train.df)` return? Do you have a column named `MEDV` in your `train.df` object?

Comment: Actually I did not. I added 13 to by selectead.var vector in line 10. That seemed to help.

Comment: I can only assume, then, that MEDV is column 13 in your original data set.  For future questions, **please** read up on how to construct a [mcve]; otherwise we're playing guessing games ...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are (at least) two problems here.

Assuming this is the same Boston Housing data set as the `BostonHousing` data set in the `mlbench` package, the median value variable is `medv`, not `MEDV`: R is case-sensitive.

```r
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
names(BostonHousing)
 [1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas"    "nox"     "rm"      "age"    
 [8] "dis"     "rad"     "tax"     "ptratio" "b"       "lstat"   "medv"
```

The second problem is that you extracted only variables 1, 4, and 6 from the data set: this doesn't include the response variable.

```r
names(BostonHousing)[selected.var]
[1] "crim" "chas" "rm"
```

If I do

```r
selected.var <- c("crim", "chas", "rm", "medv")
```

instead of {1,4,6}, run the code to define the training set, and then use

```r
housing.lm <- lm(medv ~ ., data = train.df)
```

I get something reasonably sensible.

(It's possible that you have a version of the data set where `MEDV` is capitalized, and you only have the second problem. In any case, check the names of your data set ...)